# ReactJs: How to recover from errors in a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a live code editor for my library and, because of that, some components may trigger an exception while rendering due to invalid input. That's a completely expected behavior.

My problem now is that the entire page crashes when the input is invalid.

What I wanted was a way to `catch` the exception and show a red alert where the component should be. Again, it's a live code editor, things are expected to break.

I can't find a way around this. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

IME, every `render()` implementation must properly handle exceptions while building its component subtree.

Due to the way React buffers DOM updates, though, the sub-components are not `render`-ed deeper in the stack, it's more like:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  render() { return <div className="wrapper"><Child question={think()} /></div> }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() { return <div className="child-stuff" /> }
}

React.render(<Main answer={42} />, document.getElementById('reactRoot'))
```

..will call `Main#render`, which will then *queue* `Child.render` for execution, then execute it either later on the event loop, or on the next tick, etc.

This async execution means you can only reliably catch exceptions in a `#render` method for the code it executes directly (`think()`), but not what the child component's `#render` does.

I believe this precludes higher-order components from handling arbitrary exceptions (i.e. program/data errors), though I agree with Filip that this is otherwise a great answer for general (predictable) error handling.

See [React #2461](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2461) for more details, but I believe this is the current state of things.

Answer (score 0):

A good point where you can interject is when your creating React elements, via `React.render`, `React.createElement`, `React.cloneElement`:

```
try {
  React.render(<Editor />, container);
} catch (e) {
  // Something went wrong. Let's recover.
  React.render(<ItsNotMeItsYourComputer />, container);
}
```

So doing something like this in a global context would help you recover when creating and mounting your editor in the DOM. For better control, however, you would probably want to write either higher-order components or custom controller views which have a specific way of how they create and manage child components, with the added ability to render a generic `Error` view in case things go wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understand where I should put this. I'm in the Render method, I'm supposed to return something like <Component/>. But Component will failt because it's props are invalid. I don't believe your call to Render is exactly valid though.. you are supposed to pass a  DOMElement.

Comment: @andrerpena somewhere you have to have a call to `React.render()`.  That's where Filip is saying the exception can be caught (even if it's thrown deep inside the component tree).

Comment: I'm not sure this is a complete strategy, if anything like Flux, event handlers, etc. ever mutate any state deeper in the tree. I've just tried it at the top of my fairly deep React/Flux project to try to catch an exception deep in a leaf, and my understanding of React's async buffered DOM mutations is such that the stack from the outermost `React.render` is entirely gone once the first render is done.